# how to make RTSP request in html5 or in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, rtsp, darwin

How to make request "rtsp://localhost:554/sample_100kbit.mp4"? (in HTML5 or Javascript)
I want to access video streaming data which source is present on Darwin server

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's possible without an additional browser plugin.

The `<video>` tag in HTML5 requires the content to be served over HTTP.

Flash supports streaming using their own protocol (RTMP) and there are products available that will proxy between RTSP and RTMP.  However that would require you to run your own server and provision the bandwidth between user -> proxy -> content.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 don't support rtsp URL, and maybe MSE or WebRTC can help 
refer [RTSP solution for JavaScript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440265/rtsp-solution-for-javascript-html5)